# MVCScaffolding, Entity Framework Model First, many-to-many scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am using Entity Framework Model First. There are 2 entities in my Model..

1. User
2. Role

I want to use MVC scaffolding (using VS 2012 or 2010) for this relationship.

From some posts in 20111 many-many was not supported. is it still not supported? If nto supported is there any workaround?

I can not change the Model (because database will be generated from it) however i am mainly looking forward creating Users, Creating Roles and Assigning roles to Users. if some workaround using one-many can give me above scaffolded views and controller I will be ok with that.

Thanks
Nachi